# mvc: Returning a view in mvc does not work

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Does anyone know why this is not working for me? I have not been able to return to a view
I specified.
return this.View("InvoiceDetail"); is not working. It resides in a folder called Rental\InvoiceDetail.cshtml

```
                    [HttpPost]
                            public ActionResult Index(RentalCustomerViewmodel ameRentalVm)
                            {
                                ......
                                ......
                                ......
                                            if (connInsite.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                                            {
                                                connInsite.Close();
                                            }

                                            return this.View("InvoiceDetail");
                                .....
                                .....
                                .....
                                return View();
                            }



                            public ActionResult InvoiceDetail()
                            {

                                return View();
                            }
```

Comment: Is your controller RentalController?

Comment: What is the exception?? BTW, don't have to have `this.` in `return this.View("InvoiceDetail");`

Answer (score 0):

return ***this.View("InvoiceDetail")***; is return a ***view*** only not ***redirect*** to an action of any controller. So when you request the index action and return this.View("InvoiceDetail") it search the view in your corresponding view folder (Rental).

If you want to ***redirect*** to a action then use ***RedirectToAction***("InvoiceDetail");

In your case it will be

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(RentalCustomerViewmodel ameRentalVm)
{
      ......
      ......
      ......                         
      if (connInsite.State == ConnectionState.Open)
      {
         connInsite.Close();
      }

      //return this.View("InvoiceDetail");

      RedirectToAction("InvoiceDetail");

      .....
      .....          
      .....

      return View();
}



public ActionResult InvoiceDetail()
{

   return View();
}
```